# Question about a vector equation from course literature

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm re-doing an exam on linear algebra, and I don't agree on one thing from the course literature, and I wanted to check here if there's something im missing.

It's a proof for theorem of basis, and it starts like this:

Assume $$\vec{a_1}=(a_{11},...,a_{1n}), \vec{a_2}=(a_{21},...,a_{2n}), \vec{a_p}=(a_{p1},...,a_{pn})$$ and consider the equation $$x_1\vec{a_1}+x_2\vec{a_2}+...+x_p\vec{a_p}=\vec{b}$$ where $$\vec{b} = (b_1,..,b_n)$$

and where they say that this equal the system

$$\begin{cases} a_{11}x_1+...+a_{p1}x_p=b1 \\ a_{12}x_1+...+a_{p2}x_p=b2 \\ \vdots \\   a_{1n}x_1+...+a_{pn}x_p=bn\end{cases}$$

Which I don't agree on since the first index says which row we are on, or am I stupid?

Comment: According to you, what is $x_1\vec{a_1}$?

Comment: Well it is what I've written, but shouldn't there be a swap of index? because now the second index says which row we are on?

Comment: I see and agree it is at least an awkward notation.

Comment: Even though it’s awkward to type, this is why we should write vectors in column notation.

Answer (score 1):

The course literature is correct.

Every equation of the system corresponds to one entry in the vectorial equation. Since the vectors are row vectors and the equations in the system are stacked in a column, the indices transpose.

Answer (score 0):

It might be easiest to see what's happening if we write it out explicitly for a small system. Let's have $n = 2, p = 3$, so then we have the vectors:

$$\begin{eqnarray} \vec{a}_1 & = & (a_{11}, a_{12}) \\
\vec{a}_2 & = & (a_{21}, a_{22}) \\
\vec{a}_3 & = & (a_{31}, a_{32}) \\
\vec{b} & = & (b_1, b_2) \end{eqnarray}$$

and the equation

$$x_1 \vec{a}_1 + x_2 \vec{a}_2 + x_3 \vec{a}_3 = \vec{b}$$

Then if we expand this out, we get:

$$\begin{eqnarray} x_1 \vec{a}_1 + x_2 \vec{a}_2 + x_3 \vec{a}_3 & = & 
x_1 (a_{11}, a_{12}) + x_2 (a_{21}, a_{22}) + x_3 (a_{31}, a_{32}) \\
& = & (x_1 a_{11}, x_1 a_{12}) + (x_2 a_{21}, x_2 a_{22}) + (x_3 a_{31}, x_3 a_{32}) \\
& = & (x_1 a_{11} + x_2 a_{21} + x_3 a_{31}, x_1 a_{12} + x_2 a_{22} + x_3 a_{32}) \\
& = & (b_1, b_2) \\
\implies x_1 a_{11} + x_2 a_{21} + x_3 a_{31} & = & b_1 \\
\textrm{and } x_2 a_{21} + x_2 a_{22} + x_3 a_{33} & = & b_2 \end{eqnarray}$$

So while it is common to have matrix notation $a_{ij}$ have $i$ refer to the row and $j$ to the column, the way the values are defined in this case means that $j$ is referring to which component of the vectors we're looking at, so that when we write one row per component that winds up with $j$ being a row index and hence $i$ becomes a column index.

Answer (score 0):

In case it is helpful in making the "transpose" that is happening in the notation here more obvious, the start of the proof sets, for $i=1,2 \ldots, n$
$$
\vec{a_i} = (a_{ij})_{j=1}^n = (a_{i1},a_{i2},\ldots,a_{in})
$$
to be a row vector (*i.e.* a $1\times n$ matrix) and write the equation it wants to consider as
$$
\tag{$\dagger$}
x_1\vec{a_1}+\ldots+x_n\vec{a_n} = \vec{b},
$$
where $\vec{b}=(b_1,b_2,\ldots,b_n)$ is again a row vector. The natural way to put this into matrix form would be to set $\vec{x} = (x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)$ to be the row vector given by the $x_i$s and $R$ to be the $n\times n$ matrix with the rows given by the $\vec{a_i}s$, since then ($\dagger$) becomes $\vec{x}.R=\vec{b}$: more explicitly:
$$
\vec{x}.R = (x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)\left(\begin{array}{c}\vec{a_1} \\\ \vec{a_2} \\\ \vdots \\\ \vec{a_n} \end{array}
\right) = x_1\vec{a_1}+x_2\vec{a_2}+\ldots x_n\vec{a_n}
$$

In the last part of the proof that you quote, however, rather than considering the matrix equation $\vec{x}R = \vec{b}$, the transpose map is applied, which gives:
$$
(\vec{x}.R)^\intercal = b^{\intercal}, \text{ or } R^{\intercal} \vec{x}^\intercal = \vec{b}^{\intercal}
$$